# auto completion on generated java code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, code-generation, bytecode-manipulation, apt

I would like to make auto generated code available to eclipse editor for auto completion

Following cases:

1) Xml document describing a data model and java processor is creating java source code.
  Right now I need to run ant script to create java source.
  Could that be triggered by change of xml document?

2) Class is extended with new methods by apt processor.
  Is it possible to register apt processors to the jdt?

3) Instrumented java byte code creates new methods.
  Is it possible to make the auto completion read through a class loader which is doing byte code weaving?

Answer (score 0):

The first case could be addressed with your **[ant script registered as a builder](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm)**.
It is detailed in "[Creating a project builder Ant buildfile](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm)"

[image]

You can setup this builder to run on each file save.

But I am not sure about the second and third cases, except to see see if the completion works after a "refresh project".